# Why am i getting a fatal error?

Tags: php, sql, database, authentication

Here is the snippet of code that is causing the error.

```
public function storeUser($email, $password) {

    require_once 'include/user.config.inc.php';

    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    //echo $uuid;
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    //echo $hash;
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    //echo $encrypted_password;
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    //echo $salt;


    $query = "INSERT INTO user_table (unique_id, email_id, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES ( :uuid, :email, :encrypted_password, :salt, NOW()) ";
    $query_params = array(
        ':uuid' => $uuid,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':encrypted_password' => $encrypted_password,
        ':salt' => $salt
    );
    try {

        //These two statements run the query against the database table.
        $stmt = $db -> prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt -> execute($query_params);

    } catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error! Problem with first query!";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }
```

}

I am getting an error:

Notice: Undefined variable: db

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

It seems that $query and $query_params is causing the problem but I don't know why.  It seems right to me.

Here's the other snippet of code

```
if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {

             // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already exist";
            echo json_encode($response);

        } else {

            $db->storeUser($email, $password);

        }
```

Comment: Where is `$db` defined? PHP says it is missing and thus fails ...

Comment: its initialized in include/user.config.inc.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a guess here...

`require_once` only includes the file ***once***, ever*. You have probably `required` that file before elsewhere, it's not getting loaded again, your `$db` variable is nowhere to be found.

<sub>* In the current script execution.</sub>

Comment: yes this was the problem but now I am getting this error "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()" how do i end the previous session as i have two functions accessing the database on separate occasions.  I added the code where the two functions are called

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize your $db object.

You need something like the following before "$stmt = $db -> prepare($query);"

```
$db = new mydbclass();
```